# Use of sine in derivation of the Abbe limit

Tags: optics

In some books (here: Demtröder Experimentalphysik 2) when deriving the Abbe limit this equation is used:

> the maximum aperture angle alpha is determined by
>
> $$\sin(\alpha) = (D/2)/f$$
>
> D/f is the numerical aperture (NA)

but you have to use the tangent, don't you?

[image]

Or is there any reason this is right?

Comment: Consider the small angle limit...

Comment: that is what came in my mind, too. But we talk about angles up to 90°+ degrees.

Comment: If your resolution limit involves angles near 90 degrees, you have a problem...

Comment: alpha then is about 45°, so this is far beyond 5-7° to use small angle approximation.

Comment: It would be useful to see a resource which quotes this result. It looks like should be a tan to me too